# Notation of sphere in $\Bbb{R}^n$.

Tags: differential-geometry

In $\Bbb{R}^n$, the sphere centred at $x\in \Bbb{R}^n$ with radius $l$ is called $S^{n-1}(x,l)$ or an $(n-1)$-sphere.

Why do we called it an $(n-1)$-sphere? It's certainly not defined on $\Bbb{R}^{n-1}$ instead of $\Bbb{R}^n$.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: People are all saying more or less the same thing in different ways.  The $n-1$ refers to the dimension of the sphere itself, rather than the dimension of the space in which the sphere lives.  If instead of talking about points with distance precisely $l$ from $x$, you talked about points having distance $\leq l$ from $x$, you'd call that an $n$-dimensional disc.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since the sphere is defined as the set of point **on** the sphere and not inside it, a sphere in $\mathbb{R}^n$ is just a $n-1$ dimensional surface.

Another way of looking at this is that every point on the sphere with a given radius can be expressed by $n-1$ angles.

Comment: $n-1$ local coordinates in general (angular or not)

Comment: @oldrinb - for the sphere with a given radius, the common characterization involves $n-1$ angles. Of course you can invent other ones, but I find the angles representation gives some helpful intuition.

Comment: yes @nbubis the angles correspond to arcs of curvilinear coordinate axes thoush yes?

Comment: @oldrinb - The [wiki page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N-sphere) describes the angles under the section "Spherical coordinates".

Comment: yes @nbubis I am familiar, but my point was that the angles themselves are just like 'arcs' on circular coordinate axes :p

Answer (score 1):

Locally, the sphere looks like $\Bbb{R}^{n - 1}$, and the $(n-1)$-sphere is an $(n - 1)$-dimensional manifold. The ball, on the other hand, is an $n$-manifold.

Answer (score 1):

As a manifold, the $(n-1)$-sphere has dimension $n - 1$. This means that close up, any small part of the $(n-1)$-sphere will look like $\Bbb R^{n-1}$. To be precise, every point $x \in S^{n-1}$ has an open neighborhood that is homeomorphic to $\Bbb R^{n-1}$.